# How bundle Product doesn't have choice?Difference b/w Bundle Vs Group

Tags: magento2.2, bundled-product, grouped-products

According to my knowledge In **"Grouped Product" user has the choice but in "Bundle Product" user doesn't have the choice.**

To practically check "Grouped & Bundle" Product feature, I created a Test product of both type.

**Please visit here to see screenshots:-**

**1- Grouped Product:-**

http://nimb.ws/iR2M8z

http://nimb.ws/8WMOQ1

**2-Bundle Product:-**

http://nimb.ws/5sz7Hp

http://nimb.ws/MlKJEC

But as you can see the screenshot user is not restricted to choose all product. he/she still has a choice to choose the product for "Bundle Product".**so how can we say that "Bundle Product" doesn't have any choice?**

Please let me know how they are different?

Waiting for your reply!!!

Answer (score 0):

According to my observation here is the main difference:-

Please visit on the screenshot:-

http://nimb.ws/kHWysK

http://nimb.ws/4hk5ar

http://nimb.ws/IS0i64

http://nimb.ws/QDVaXB

To addition anything, please comment.